# Have PowerShell create a shortcut based on OS bits

Tags: powershell

I'm tying to deploy a PowerShell script via a SCCM task sequence. As part of that I need to copy and rename a shortcut from the `C:\Program Files x86\TESTapp\test.exe` directory. I have that done, however I was just informed that some client are on 32bit OS's.

What is the best way to have PowerShell determine what path to take, **ie: "Program Files (x86)" or "Program Files"**

Here is what I have that's currently not working:

```
Switch (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture {
  "32-bit" {$PF = "Program Files"}
  "64-bit" {$PF = "Program Files x86"}
}

$TargetFile = "$env:C:\$PF\TESTapp\Test.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\NewName-Test.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is - you forgot the () on the switch expression:

```
Switch ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture) {
  "32-bit" {$PF = "Program Files"}
  "64-bit" {$PF = "Program Files x86"}
}

$TargetFile = "C:\$PF\TESTapp\Test.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\NewName-Test.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: there are space in the environment vars `ProgramFile` and `ProgramFiles(x86)` and there is no env var beginning with `C:`

Comment: Doh! What a dumb mistake, I guess I've been working on this too long.

Thanks for the help, it works perfectly now.

Comment: its okay, I didn't spot it at first also ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Switch (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture {
  "32-bit" {$PF = "$env:ProgramFiles"}
  "64-bit" {$PF = "$env:ProgramFiles(x86)"}
}
$TargetFile = "$PF\TESTapp\Test.exe"
If (Test-Path $TargetFile) {
    $ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\NewName-Test.lnk"
    $WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```